# arm neon BSL instruction for floating point

Tags: assembly, arm, intrinsics, neon

Is there an inline asm instruction equivalent for neon intrinsic **vbslq_f32**?

In  [intrinsic manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0073a/IHI0073A_arm_neon_intrinsics_ref.pdf) there is written 
**BSL Vd.16B,Vn.16B,Vm.16B** as asm equivalent for **vbslq_f32**. But in [asm manual](https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/41836-102-1-229511/ARM.Reference_Manual.pdf) there is not implementation for 4S, there is only "8B or 16B (though an assembler should accept any valid format)" and it doesn't work with floats.

Comment: `VBSL` is bitwise, so you can just use it, should work for floats as well. Post [MCVE] if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any data type for bitwise operations.

Only the vector length matters, either 64bit or 128bit which you specify by 8b or 16b.